# Cannot display the data from $http request when using $routeParams

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
 demoApp
 .controller('DetailController', function($http, $scope, $routeParams) {
     $http({
         method: 'POST',
         url: 'Webservice.asmx/getRecord',
         data: {}
     }).success(function(data) {
         $scope.items = data.d[$routeParams.ID - 1];
         console.log($scope.items);
     });
 });
```

Why my controller doesn't display its data on its view when I use the `$routeParams`, but when I remove it from the code the data shows properly. Unfortunately, I don't have filter on that case.

this is how i call the $scope.items

```
        <tr id="theList" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" ng-repeat="item in items" >
         <td>
                {{item._empID}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{item._firstname}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{item._lastname}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{item._address}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{item._city}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{item._pincode}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{item._state}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{item._country}}
            </td>
        </tr>
```

data in console.log:

```
 [
 Object
 $$hashKey: "004"
 __type: "WebService+Employee"
 _address: "add1"
 _city: "city1"
 _country: "count1"
 _empID: "1"
 _firstname: "fname1"
 _lastname: "lname1"
 _pincode: "pin1"
 _state: "state1"
 __proto__: Object
 ]

 Object
 __type: "WebService+Employee"
 _address: "add1"
 _city: "city1"
 _country: "count1"
 _empID: "1"
 _firstname: "fname1"
 _lastname: "lname1"
 _pincode: "pin1"
 _state: "state1"
 __proto__: Object
```

Comment: well, does the success callback execute?  if so, what does data look like in the console?  update your post when you have that info

Comment: with params -> **[>Object]**, without -> **>Object**. i don't have any idea why they are different in case of having brackets[].

Comment: with that bracket[] the data will show perfectly..

Comment: ok.  so it's an array with one object.  so what's happening in your view?  how are you using scope.items?

Comment: because data.d is an array.  data itself is just an object.  you should have posted the expanded object (data).  that's half the point of logging to the console.  you can open it up and see everything

Comment: yes. the data are the same except the brackets[]. i don't know if that  is the issue but why it is not showing in the view.

Comment: the object that has no brackets[] shows only empty rows..

Comment: you could just post the whole output ( console.log(data) ) for us though like I requested earlier, instead of trying to describe it and us trying to guess

Comment: hi @thescientist, i'd posted the data. the first one is the data that can show in the view and the other one is having a result of empty row in my table.

Comment: have you tried by remove all those other data-* attributes?  just reduced it down to a very simple ng-repeat?  Also, are you sure it's not a CSS or markup issue?  Are you verifying in the source nothing is generated through your developer tools?  What if you hardcode a row of data, will it show?